# Open or Close the Parentheses

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, parsing, balanced-string

Every phone needs a calculator app. Because of the limited screen real estate, the developer of mine has decided to save some buttons. Instead of having two dedicated bracket buttons - one for open `(` and one for close `)` - there is just a single bracket button `()`. It looks something like this:

[image: My phone's calculator app]

When the button is pressed, it places a bracket. Based on the input given so far, it predicts whether the bracket should be open `(` or close `)`.

By trial and error, I have found the button to follow these rules:

- If there are no unmatched brackets, the next bracket will **always** be open `(`.
- Else, if the last character is a numeral `0123456789` or close `)` bracket, the next bracket will be close `)`.
- Else, if the last character is an operator `+-*/` or open `(` bracket, the next bracket will be open `(`.

### The challenge

Based on the given input and the rules mentioned above, predict whether the button places an open `(` or close `)` bracket.

### Input

Either a string, an array of characters, or anything equivalent. The input will **only** contain the following characters*: `0123456789+-*/()`

### Output

An open `(` or close `)` bracket **or** any two consistent values representing them.

### Test cases

```
""                  -> "("
"(1+"               -> "("
"(1+(2/3"           -> ")"
"(1+(2/3)"          -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8"       -> "("
"(1+(2/3))-8*("     -> "("
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5"   -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5)"  -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5))" -> "("
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

#### Note

* The actual calculator also includes the symbols `.%`, but you don't need to care about those.

Comment: May we assume the input won't contain wonky brackets, e.g. `)(1+2`?

Comment: @pxeger Yes, you may. You can expect the input to be typed on the calculator, too.

Comment: May the input contain things like `23(` or invalid expressions such as `4/*3`?

Comment: @Arnauld You can assume that it doesn't contain either.

Comment: These rules aren't correct. For example, the expression ((5+2)(7+3)+4)*2 will not be handled correctly. Instead, your rules will output ((5+2))7+3(+4)*2

Comment: @DonThousand That is indeed what the calculator does. If you want to force `((5+2)(7+3)+4)*2`, then you have to include a multiplication sign after `((5+2)`. The rules are fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

## [JavaScript (Node.js v11.6.0)](https://nodejs.org), 48 bytes

```javascript
a=>/k/.test(eval("try{eval(a+')')}catch(e){e}"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc69CsIwFMXx3acIZ@m9ljaoCC71XUJM/QqNNKEgpc8erYtQEe6ZzvAb/jczmGj76yNVXTi53DbZNEd913VyMZEbjCek/jl@nikLLniyJtkLOR7dBOZsQxeDd7UPZ2oJUMsxK60VCKsFpU0JOaWt3uGH8j/KkFOuDpAFzHRNkFPaQxYw03ezmDK@AfkF)

We try to append a character `')'` to the end of expression and `eval` it. Node v11.6.0 (as current version on TIO) may:

- Calculate the expression if the expression is valid

  - The calculate result may only contain characters `/[0-9INafinty]/`
- Report error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` if the `)` should not be there
- Report error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` if the `)` is valid there

So we just need to check if the result contains letter `"k"`.

Comment: [42](https://tio.run/##jc69CsIwFMXx3acIZ8m9hhpUBJf6LiGmflCb0oaClD57tC5CRbhnOsNv@N/d4Hrf3dpUNPEcclVmV560NmFwNSF1z/HznNH80Dx5l/yVAo9hAmcfmz7WYVPHC1UEqOWYlbUKhNWC0tZATmln9/ih/I8y5JSLI2QBM10T5JQOkAXM9N0spoxvQH4B)

Comment: maybe this count as 39

Comment: @l4m2 Why not simply claim that "My function return results via throwing an exception", and only use code `a=>eval(a+')m')`?

Comment: because I'm not familiar enough with rules

Comment: @l4m2 I'm not sure about the rules. Maybe you can post it as another answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/) on Linux, <del>82</del> <del>79</del> <del>66</del> 62 bytes

```c
c;f(*x){for(c=0;*x;++x)*x&22?:*x&1?--c:++c;c*=*--x&16|*x==41;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBLTsMwEIb3OcXIVZE9riEJFKEa0wtwg6aLyEnaSMFFTooshZw9OIaiUjqLeXzjx/yjhW5ysxtHLSuKjvXVwVKtYolOcu4Yups0Xa98SNZC6BXnWmpUKIQnj5/olHpI5DDOaqObY1E@t11RH273L1FUmw7e8trQKcntTi9A73ML6POPzZZBH4G3qYtd2XbtZgsKenglZOEdTfgp0vTu/jxnfwomni5rpP8JXV5j7Cr8oZc24RgGGeb2i4JJGiJM0/vRgwj5LUaGivOTynCDhhaTv@Td@gcqSuYFZGTetBnJjP/Db@r85BC8LbujNRDLaBi/AA)

Expects a nul-terminated ASCII wide string (4 bytes per character). Returns false (zero) for open bracket and true (nonzero) for close bracket.

- Thank you to @AZTECCO for golfing off 13 bytes!
- And thank you to @jdt for golfing off 4 more bytes. (This required switching to clang; the original answer was for gcc.)

Comment: @AZTECCO You've been busy! And I had no idea C has an Elvis operator now — that's awesome.

Comment: @jdt Very cool. I will include Clang separately, if that's ok with you, since I had gcc originally.

Comment: Sorry for noticing now but it fails on higly unbalanced brackets, e.g. "(((((((((((((()", use `*=` instead of `&=` to fix it [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBdboMwDIDfOYVF1Slxmg1YN03NWC@wG5Q@oAAtEkunQKdIjLMzk6lT29UP/vlsJ7a11E1uduOoVcXQ8b46WKbTSKFTQjiO7i5J1isy8VoIvZJSK40pSknk@Rtdmi5jNYyz2ujmWJSvbVfUh/v9WxDUpoOPvDZscnK70wvQ@9wCkv@12XLoAyChLEJXtl272UIKPbyH4YIUi8XJsuTh8dznFwGXL9cxsv@EPd1i/CYkSvBaptoIBuXHpjvBtBn@Dk@T@x0U4GSVj4Q4Lek7mE9x9Uc@LT1QsXBeQBbOmzYLM0N/0KHOKwevbdkdrYFIBcP4Aw "C (clang) – Try It Online") btw lol Elvis operator

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer (and merged them). I also swapped the `--c` and `++c` to keep the results nonnegative, for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: I don't think you need to mention the change from gcc to clang. Your answer is still for C :-)

Comment: @ChrisBouchard about the elvis operator: according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#Languages_supporting_the_Elvis_operator) leaving out the second operand in the ternary operator is supported as a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_4.html#SEC70) since 2001, so GCC-style C is probably the origin of the elvis operator :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„()S¢Ëžh')«Iθå≠~
```

-2 bytes by outputting `1` for `(` and `0` for `)`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9vc2FiaWX//@KAnigpU8Kiw4vFvmgnKcKrSc64w6XiiaB@//8oMSsoMi8zKSktOCo) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Rw3zNDSDDy063H10X4a65qHVled2HF76qHNB3X@d/9FKSjpKGobaEFLDSN8YwdJEYmrqWqDytDTQ@RqmmCKaWIQ0lWIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
„()        # Push string "()"
   S       # Convert it to a character-list: ["(",")"]
    ¢      # Count the "(" and ")" in the (implicit) input-string
     Ë     # Check whether both are the same
žh         # Push builtin "0123456789"
  ')«     '# Append a ")"
     Iθ    # Push the last character of the input-string
       å≠  # Check that it's NOT in the string "0123456789)"
~          # Bitwise-OR to check if at least one is truthy
           # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
‛()$vO≈9ʀ\)J?tc∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%28%29%24vO%E2%89%889%CA%80%5C%29J%3Ftc%E2%88%A8&inputs=%27%281%2B%27&header=&footer=)

0 for `(` and 1 for `)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda L:"0">cmp(*map(L.count,"()"))*L[-1:]!=")"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBNC4JAEAbg@/6K7b04Y9onQQjrL/DorTzYh7Sgu0ttQb/elIigdG7DM7zDjHv6izWrtlL7ti6bw6mUWYIF0mPjKGxKR9nsaO/GRyAGc5jt4mVSTBQYba6CIADkX8WpBEGAllOME63ma/wQf4kxThxvMRzYU0gYJ9pgOLCnfucYdfYO7I6e3VytPWFvwKKyV@mlNjJPhNSRVf3bzo@yjvxn7h3KQrqrNl3PhF1FmgulLIv2BQ)

Based on @wasif's Python 3 answer; shortened using `cmp` which is not available in Python 3.

True for "("

False for ")"

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -nMv5.10, 23 bytes

```perl
say!/[\d)]$/||eval&&!$@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJRPzomRTNWRb@mJrUsMUdNTVHF4f9/Lg1DbRDWMNI3htGacIamrgUyW0sDladhis7XxBDQ/JdfUJKZn1f8Xzfvv66vqZ6hgZ4BAA)

Prints true/1 for `(` and false/empty string for `)`.

And for eight extra bytes we can print `(` and `)` like this: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJRPzomRTNWRb@mJrUsMUdNTVHFwV5dQ91KXVP9/38uDUNtENYw0jeG0ZpwhqauBTJbSwOVp2GKztfEEND8l19QkpmfV/xfN@@/rq@pnqGBngEA) 31 bytes. The `eval&&!$@` checks if the input expression have balancing parentheses by using the Perl compiler to check if it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 75 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS=".|"}RT~/\(/{++n}RT~/\)/{--n}END{print n?RT~/[\)0-9]/?")":"(":"("}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9GqTYopE4/RkO/Wls7D8LW1K/W1c2rdfVzqS4oyswrUcizB4lHx2ga6FrG6tsraSpZKWmAce3//wA)

```
BEGIN{RS=".|"}
```

Starts reading the input one character at a time, which are stored in the `RT` variable, by the way.

```
RT~/\(/{++n}
RT~/\)/{--n}
```

If the character is a `(`, increments `n` by one. If it  is `)`, decrements `n` by one.

```
END{print 
          n?
            RT~/[\)0-9]/?
                         ")"
                        :"("
           :"("
   }
```

If `n` equals zero, i.e., there are as many `(` as `)`, prints `(`. If `n` is different from zero, evaluates the last character (registered in `RT`). If it is a number or `)`, prints a `)`, otherwise, prints `(`.

Comment: Nice!  Changing the non-BEGIN/END clauses to this `n+=(RT=="(")-RT==")"{}` seems to work and shaves off 2 chars.

Comment: @cnamejj That was a nice idea! But I couldn't make it work without parenthesizing that second comparison, like this: `n+=(RT=="(")-(RT==")"){}`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9GqTZP21YjKMTWVklDSVMXwtJU0qyudfVzqS4oyswrUcizDwqp04@O0TTQtYzVtwdKWwEVg3Dt//8ahtoaRvrGAA "AWK – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 30 bytes

```
{(^"(*+-/"?*|x)>~+/-/x=/:"()"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJx1z9EKgjAUxvH7PcU4dHGmjGkRxEb2IGLYjRAFgXgxMX323BRTt53bH3yHfyU7vANGMRdwi76aZUMsuNBXIQEZ9IQ0sjvk7VDLilKqVfl5KSyrx/OttGpVzYqeNDmAos4lhRFMYwcXwaM4bTRdC1vTVhi/LJjsJcLZPIJna86aEfvPL4bGNSIIgFvKMwoIxLaGycbuiP2JQZhMrn9w7g3TGOwfnIrDNNo0+AOtr2Ho)

Returns `0` for `"("` and `1` for `")"`.

- `~+/-/x=/:"()"` determine whether or not the input contains a balanced number of parenthesis, i.e. that the number of `"("`s minus the number of `")"`s is 0
- `(^"(*+-/"?*|x)` determine if the last character is one that should be followed by a `"("` (i.e. one of `"+-*/("`) or not
- `(...)>...` use `>` as material nonimplication (i.e. only return a truthy value if the left side is truthy and the right side isn't)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>52</s>  51 bytes

Expects an array of characters. Returns `0` for `(`, or `1` for `)`.

```javascript
a=>a.map(c=>q+=-(d=c>-1,C=c==')')|c<')',q=0)|q&&d|C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc@xDoIwEMbx3acgN8Cd0FY0Jg5eFx7DODQFDAYpiHHi3StMJmpMesu3/Ib/Xc3TjPbe9A/RubLyNXvD2sib6dGyHlIWWLLVIs8KtswJJTTZ4zzZwBuahjgup8Jb142urWTrLljjSUoJEH3emShSKgKE1Q@PeQqBHrdqB9@e/nmCQE/iAAE9i18jBHrcQ0DP4uc/wjzBu8e/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>               // a[] = input array of characters
a.map(c =>         // for each character c in a[]:
  q +=             //   update q
    -(             //   which keeps track of the balance of parentheses
      d = c > -1,  //   d = digit flag
      C = c == ')' //   C = closing parenthesis flag
    )              //   decrement q if C is set
    | c < ')',     //   or increment it if c is '('
  q = 0            //   start with q = 0
) |                // end of map()
q &&               // return 1 if q is not 0 (unbalanced parentheses)
d                  // and the last character was either a digit
  | C              // or a closing parenthesis
```

Answer (score 3):

## C# (8.0), <s>76</s> <s>68</s> 64 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

-1 byte thanks to [Aaroneous Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaroneous-miller)*

```cs
bool p(char[]i)=>i.Sum(x=>x<42?x*2-81:0)==0||i[^1]<48&i[^1]!=41;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5RS4RAFEaf119xGyLv3dTUDGTdcYl97SEq6ME1MJvWgc1ZZiYwXH@7RUEh7cvHOefpq41fGzmOz0rtYI91U@milMRzGdy/v2HH826ZxKtuHvtptAiJ8/BwkMVTVC6T9OwbTngSZaOxWrbbogQrjF1XRhjg0Dszxjz4WozOfwHji8uJ0NTIT5k39Tn@L3h1rNHRSMwZMudVaVHVDf58BQOy/btLzmytWqN2InjU0oob2QpkfTiAn0MfDcw7ZRvWm2HDWHBbvdzJbWMxDgm8PZrgQV1rXX0gEazARXfhkkuZM34C)
Takes not-null (but it might be empty) array of characters and outputs `true` for `(` and `false` for `)`.

Ungolfed:

```cs
bool p(char[] input){
   int sum = input.Where(x=>x<42)  // take only brackets
       .Select(x=>x*2-81)          // replace '(' with -1 and ')' with 1
       .Sum();                     // sum them 

   if(sum == 0)       // if sum is 0, brackets are balanced
       return true;
   // when left condition in || operator is true the right one isn't checked
   // this is beneficial for us because it prevents from taking last element
   // of empty array - empty input will always have balanced brackets

   char lastChar = i[^1];  // takes last character (this notation requires C# 8.0)
   
   return            // return true (opening bracket) IF:
      lastChar < 48  // last char is '/','*','-','+','(' or ')' 
      &&             // AND
      lastChar != 41;// last char isn't ')'
}
```

Comment: You can remove the space in `(char[] i)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 39 bytes

Exits truthy if a `(` should be inserted, falsy if a `)` should be inserted.

```sh
eval ${(s..)1//[^()]/;}||${(M)1%[0-9)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc3dSgMxEAXg@zzFYVghY03XtQiVRfEFvPC6VGibWTcQNtKsP9jus68JCIJ2zd3kO3PmM7ZjlD689JCPXjor9tmHrWo061HeNh7FQcf5nKuyXD1pXpf1cDymvweuzlaX5obXw8hKvbfOC/aysTB7eNdJDRuUAlI7jAGlnftHLg63GYeBErkGDYqqRt9Kl2ZAdm0AxTa8eoutoFhcwEXonBYf5b8Q51DjlLKhk5EIf565A6Uq0tWMpklflQv6RfxDTNPEZkmnCzOda5omfU2nCzPlm1OU7LvwCw)

The `eval` handles the matching (getting rid of non-`()` characters, and spawning nested subshells with spaces and `;`s to prevent `()()` or `(( ))` from erroring).

The `${(M)1%[0-9)]}` simply tries to run the last character of the input as a program if it is in `0123456789)`, failing. `||` brings the whole logic together.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 71 bytes

```
Prompt Str1
For(I,1,length(Str1
sub(Str1,I,1→Str2
O+(Ans="(→O
C+(Str2=")→C
End
0
If O≠C
not(inString("+-*/(",sub(Str1,length(Str1),1
Ans
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and displayed. Outputs `0` for `(` and `1` for `)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
ċⱮØ(Iɓ”)ØD;faƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I96ON6w7P0PA8OflRw1zNwzNcrNMSj036f7hdM/L/fyUlHSUNQ20IqWGkb4xgaSIxNXUtUHlaGuh8DVNMEU0sQppKAA)

*-1 because I actually looked at other solutions and remembered `ċ` exists*

Returns falsy (empty list) for open or truthy (nonempty list) for close. Took a hell of a lot of permuting to get here from `=€Ø(ISaṪe”)ṭØD¤Ɗ`.

```
        ØD;       Concatenate "0123456789" and
      ”)          a closing parenthesis.
           f      Keep only its elements which are also elements of
     ɓ      aƒ    the input reduced LtR by logical AND starting with:
ċⱮØ(              Count the opening and closing parentheses in the input,
    I             and subtract the opens from the closes.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
o i=elem(last i)"+-*/("||let[o,c]=[[1|c<-i,c==p]|p<-"()"]in o==c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr8jSYa0krGv7EvEgIrS0qZRH/24zV/juJDJGUUxJ0oMSvqZYw2LmDaF3Sc2VNXpyzvZ4Gl4jUfW9ngZQg@esClEcT@BM9eXcpqIA7YL7dsD4AQ)

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr8jSYa1ErKvbR6KDxEJLVqLRyb/bzBHKyTG29ighjnxhDOVVomEwvUWoFZFI@37J/HEurNfV1d0bGXeitNXkDaCGrV1BbkpZ7rd7FKAbcLIztB8) works as another 64-byter, in case there's some opportunity to golf more from there

Answer (score 3):

### php 4 (83 chars)

Edited because the initial 67 chars answer was not a function, it was a single imperative line :

Using a traditional function allowing to call *f($input)*, so the answer is printed to stdout :

```php
function f($a){$s=count_chars($a);echo$s[41]-$s[40]&&$a!=chop($a,')0..9')?')':'(';}
```

### php 7.4 (73 chars)

Using an arrow function allowing  to call *$g($input)*, the answer is returned by *$g* :

```php
$g=fn($a)=>$a!=chop($a,')0..9')&&($a=count_chars($a))[41]-$a[40]?')':'(';
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You might want to move the comment to text in the answer body, to avoid confusion about what is and isn't part of the actual code.

Comment: More fundamentally, this answer takes input as a pre-defined variable, which is [not an allowed input form](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/46076)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
k(↔k(øo[tkd\(+$ck($i|\(
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%28%E2%86%94k%28%C3%B8o%5Btkd%5C%28%2B%24ck%28%24i%7C%5C%28&inputs=%27%281%2B%282%2F%27&header=&footer=)

```
k(↔                     # When you remove all but `()` from the input
   k(øo                 # Then remove that until there is no change
       [                # Is there nothing left?
                     \( # If so, opening bracket
                    |   # Else...
        t               # Is the last character of the input...
              $c        # Contained in...
         kd\(+          # Digits + `(`?
                k($i    # Index that into `()`
```

Comment: noob here, what does "index that into )(" mean? specifically unsure what "indexing" means in this context, or how you can "index" something into a string or list

Comment: @thejonymyster in this context, "indexing X into Y" essentially means "get the X'th element of Y"

Comment: @Jitse Fixed...

Comment: This can probably lose 4 or so bytes with [decision-problem output defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19202/default-policy-for-ouput-in-decision-problems).

Comment: @UnrelatedString Yeah, but I can't be boothered fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 39 bytes

```
(?>(\()|(?<-1>\))|.)*$(?<-1>(?<=[\d)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX8PeTiNGQ7NGw95G19AuRlOzRk9TSwXCA5K20TEpmrGamv81ueI07BWB8npaXBr/uTQMtUFYw0jfGEZrwhmauhbIbC0NVJ6GKTpfE0NAEwA) Outputs `0` for `(` or `1` for `)`, but link is to test suite that maps the results for you. Explanation:

```
(?>(\()|(?<-1>\))|.)*$
```

Atomically count the `(`s and `)`s. (It needs to be atomic otherwise the `.` messes up the count of `)`s, but it's still golfier than `[^()]`.)

```
(?<-1>(?<=[\d)]))
```

Test whether there is an unclosed `(` and the last character is a digit or a `)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
∨⁼№θ(№θ)№(*+-/§θ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO/SMO1sDQxp1jDOb8UyC/UUVDSUNLUUUBwNZU04XwlDS1tXX0lHQXHEs@8lNQKkAK/1PTEklQNQ00QsP7/X8NQ@79uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` for `(`, nothing for `)`. Pretty output can be obtained by prefixing `§)(` (equivalent to `AtIndex(")(", ...)`. Explanation: Port of @wasif's Python answer.

```
  №                 Count of
    (               Literal `(`
   θ                In input string
 ⁼                  Is equal to
     №              Count of
       )            Literal `)`
      θ             In input string
∨                   Logical Or
        №           Count of
              §θ±¹  Last character of input string
         (*+-/      In literal `(*+-/`
                    Implicitly print
```

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah originally I wrote it with the `§)(` and then forgot which character was at which index...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah I noticed your comment on wasif's post, I just wanted the two fixes to be separate edits.

Answer (score 2):

## [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex), <sup><s>86</s></sup> 85 bytes

```flex
%{
p;l;
%}
%%
[(] l=!++p;
[)] p-=l=1;
[0-9] l=1;
[-+*/] l=0;
\n putchar(!!p*l+40);
%%
```

To run this code, copy the above into a file named `calc.l` and run the following (on linux/bash):

```flex
flex calc.l
gcc lex.yy.c -o calc -lfl
for t in "" "(1+" "(1+(2/3" "(1+(2/3)" "(1+(2/3))-8" "(1+(2/3))-8*(" "(1+(2/3))-8*((5" "(1+(2/3))-8*((5)" "(1+(2/3))-8*((5))"; do  
    echo -n "\"$t\" -> "
    echo $t | ./calc
    echo
done
```

and it will output either `(` or `)` to `stdout` for each test string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```ruby
->e{!!e[/[\d)]$/]&&e.count(?()>e.count(?))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y61WlExNVo/OiZFM1ZFP1ZNLVUvOb80r0TDXkPTDs7W1Kz9X6CQFq2kFGuvpKlkpaShpKCsgA507RSAElxghRqG2rjVoinUMNI3xq4YpFATVaEm8So1dS2wKMZiOUillgaGWpwqNUzR1OKwHaQSzb34VKIqhdj@HwA)

Outputs *True* for `)`, *False* for `(`.

- Thanks to @Dingus for the insights and 4 Bytes saved

To choose `)` two conditions must hold:

`!!e[/[\d)]$/]` # match($ at the end) the set of characters [numbers, ')']. 
And double negate it to transform *nil*(no match) to *false* else *true*

`e.count(?()>e.count(?))` # open brackets can be equal if balanced, else more than closed ones in which case the second condition is met.

Comment: `e.count(?()^e.count(?))`?

Comment: @emanresu A I'm not sure it's acceptable, it return false or 0 for `(` and n>0 for `)`  but false and 0 are not the same like in many other languages, I may also use =~ instead of === to check last char , it would return nil or 0 for (. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Dingus no worries, many thanks! Indexing into a regex is insane

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 17 bytes

```
$>^pNa&`[\d)]$`Na
```

Takes the partial expression as a command-line argument. Outputs `0` for open parenthesis, `1` for close parenthesis. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYbVeziCvwS1RKiY1I0Y1US_BIh4jDpaCUNQ20NI31jTU1dCy0NpVioBAA)

[Verify all test cases!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSblGOUuzC6qWlJWm6FhtV7OIK_BLVEqJjUjRjVRL8EiHiS2sVfBXSIewFN5O4NAy1QVjDSN8YRmvCGZq6FshsLQ1UnoYpOl8TQ0ATYhUA)

#### Explanation

```
$>^pNa&`[\d)]$`Na
                   a is command-line arg; p is "()" (implicit)
  ^p               Split p into a list of two parenthesis characters
    Na             Get the count of each parenthesis in the argument
$>                 Fold on > (1 if there are more open than close parens, 0 otherwise)
                   (Because we "can expect the input to be typed on the calculator,"
                   there will never be more close than open parens)
      &            Logical AND
       `      `    The following regex:
        [\d)]       Either a digit or a close paren
             $      followed by end-of-string
               N   Count matches in
                a  The argument
```

Thus:

- If the parentheses are balanced, `$>` gives `0`, which short-circuits the AND and returns `0` (open paren)
- Otherwise:

  - If the argument ends with a digit or `)`, return `1` (close paren)
  - If it doesn't, return `0` (open paren)

To get `(` and `)` as output, wrap the whole thing in `(p` ... `)` for +3 bytes.

Comment: Every time I see pip on Code Golf SE, I wonder for a moment how someone used the Python package manager to solve the challenge.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard And I always wonder how it's possible that the [Peripheral Interchange Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_Interchange_Program) is Turing-complete.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (8.0), 110 bytes

```php
<?php
$a=$argv[1];
$b=ord($a[-1]??'');
die($b>=47||$b==41&&substr_count($a,'(')>substr_count($a,')')?')':'(');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYpBDoIwEADvfceG3VWJqWI01tKHEGJaIeJFmgKe@Ptaz17mMDNxiCI3F4eowFvw6flpdGsUBDumjsA3pW6dQ2SjuldPEGpbndc1d1vpopiWMM3p/hiX95zvHRJy/ScZ2WVcf9WICOktHfZH5vKyITrxFw)

Ungolfed:

```php
<?php
$a = $argv[1];
// Get the binary value of the first byte of the last character
$lastCharAsciiCode = ord($a[-1] ?? '');
// If the last character in the string is either 0-9 (47-57) OR Closing parenthesis (41)
if ($lastCharAsciiCode >= 47 || $lastCharAsciiCode == 41) {
    // If we have more opening parenthesis than closing, return closing.
    if (substr_count($a,'(') > substr_count($a,')')) {
        die(')');
    }
}
// Return opening by default
die('(');
```

Comment: You can golf off 2 bytes by removing the newlines after the semicolons. [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBJdFWJbEovSzaMNZaJck2vyhFQyUxWtcw1t5eXV3TOiUzVUMlyc7WxLymBihta2KoplZcmlRcUhSfnF@aVwJUrKOuoa5phyGoqa5pDySsQLLW////1zDU1jDSN9bU1LXQ0tAw1QQA)

Comment: Two more suggestions: I don't think you need `?? ''` since `ord(null) == 0`; and you could replace two calls to `substr_count` with one call to `count_chars`, which returns an array indexed by character code. [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpNCsIwEEDhq7gYmhlL0dGIYkx7kBAkTYtx04b4s@rdx7p68PFyyiK3Lqe8gWAhlMfXsTfQ27kMCME17MlAtHH@TO97TKG8ViYzPEeEvrX6vCzrbTVXFUSn9779h32nSF0VKjIiglzjYXckai5bxBP9AA)

Comment: To clarify, `ord(null) == ord('') == 0`.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard The null coalesce is to prevent $a[-1] from throwing an exception in the event that $argv[1] is either an empty string or not passed. I'll have a look at your suggestion for count_chars. Thanks!

Comment: I believe accessing an undefined array entry should only be a notice, which is nonfatal. It's up to you, of course, but I don't think advisory messages would be held against you as long as the code produces the correct result.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard Yeah, it is a notice by default. 

Got it down to [104 Bytes](https://tio.run/##FchNDoIwEEDhq7iY0BkJkWI1xjJykKYxbSHWDTT1Z8Xdq6xevpdiKqUfUkw7cAwuP75GWg2elzwiONNISxoCh@Uzv@8huvz6b9Ljc0IIRrWWeau06wr@xqqrKvA9q/NmZtUOAsVVkCBdSkFZY3c4EjWXPeKJfg "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <del>107</del> 104 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|(|(n,x)|n==0||x)(s.chars().fold((0,true),|v,c|(v.0+match c{'('=>1,')'=>-1,_=>0},c<'0'&&c!=')')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLRbpswFH3nK278EK5XhySrqk2k5GHT3qf1AyLkmAaVGIYvbaTAt2fXhDRVV6T6ARsf33OOz3XdODo1zoCjbRznZRz/aLI/Jt2ugszCPs0tSjhCYQiy5NS6eOqobrFFqw6ytUmyaNuDRBfpXVo7lFFWFlvEhaK6MVK1z0q3@BwtbvYp6R3oY4hhsl6qUPI0W6pNsl50St@Hi3A61ZOE96WUJ4BVAJCVNRS5NZDbqz9eeFNRUeonPzHuvEc@DzCfgzcPZBzplK@V1eWey6uGetzfA/tfBeZQGU1mKyGBis2bTQ/g1FNGjX2p0wqlXPWFVZ1bmqA4xvfLbx3M1iDUmZcPXKR/HYxuiEUbqykv7atkbVxTEOtkOH1f9NszDyeuUoU9i911cOxY6oyzZDYsfZCdKZw5cmTd4JLpfu6MfoL0kTvn6DWHHk2dMzVtzN8JjtC8CcUTdkEX@GfwNh0fTgz@FUifAj4Q231Uvv2XJvgb7xuC3N@4D9NVRU4o@tgGq9h//cgpsuZA3MtL5hFz7odp0z8cbnEoQt4pN@WLNVuU6hP1lzdpaYfLK9xXyqA7CQH/DW8RRSBweSPGIfw6vxXvIHmFpBiH5Oy7@JjQQ19QjEN4Jz4m9JDXHIOkGAj/AQ)

`true` for `(` and `false` for `)`

### Ungolfed

```rust
|s: &str| {
    // Iterate over all chars, folding from left
    let (paren_counter, ends_with_op_or_open) = s.chars().fold(
        (0, true), // Initial value for fold
        |(n,_), character| (
            // Increment for opening braces and decrement for closing ones
            n + match character { '(' => 1, ')' => -1, _ => 0 },
            // true for +-*/( but not for 0123456789)
            character < '0' && character != ')'
        )
    );
    // Return true if parentheses are balanced or the string ends
    // with an operator or open parenthesis, false otherwise
    paren_counter == 0 || ends_with_op_or_open
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
function(x)sum((x=="(")-(x==")"))&&grepl("[)0-9]",rev(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdBNC4JAEAbge79imUBmSimLoA4GHerUqY@TiIRsJdgqu2v47027aRqlwxzmMDzDOzIXPNN@cpFc6DtXofKLDqJYcSe/piLQYSwwI5U@EDPHAQSy3gMBkWHcJE8iBJem1soDU/JnsUztKCotVRKFGgFMAHJd2/OIDVm9rDUrbjGH7Tb743bwC4j2@IvZDcTZZN6CliCV4Olw/sujZrC7R9aygeweuARH@EH2BXFRI3slLr3aJ/t7VbAaOH8B)

Input is an array of characters; outputs `TRUE` if next parenthesis is close (`)`), `FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 90 chars

```
s=>s.replace(/.*?([\d)])?$/,(m,c)=>")("[s.replace(/[()]/g,m=>t+=m=='('||-1,t=0),+!(t&&c)])
```

### Test:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/.*?([\d)])?$/,(m,c)=>")("[s.replace(/[()]/g,m=>t+=m=='('||-1,t=0),+!(t&&c)])

console.log(`
""                  -> "("
"(1+"               -> "("
"(1+(2/3"           -> ")"
"(1+(2/3)"          -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8"       -> "("
"(1+(2/3))-8*("     -> "("
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5"   -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5)"  -> ")"
"(1+(2/3))-8*((5))" -> "("
`.split`
`.filter(x=>x).map(x=>x.match(/"(.*)".*"(.)"/)).map(([,x,r])=>f(x)==r).every(x=>x))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 73 bytes

```
,[+>-->[+]+[->+[--->]<<<]<[->>+<<]>>>[->>-<<],]<[,>>]->[+>[>]--<<<++<+]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoBADAO/s0u2XryWfKT0oIIgggfB99fsIWQmZH@36zm/464aAZoxkAijIkl3T5cSApITTTi0DjLnn6HW6IAjuVS1hrX3Hw)

Outputs truthy for `)` and falsy for `(`. Note that this will fail if there are 256 unmatched `(`.

[Version which outputs '(' or ')'](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoBADEN3v@QkVxcnoeRHSgcVBBEcBL//zFkITUL7tmc97@Pdr9ZqgGYMJMIoKaS7pysSMiS7NdmqtpLZ7xnaKh1wJIehM7rcLPSIf1JwHcWPqmJNrZWCecTyAQ) (not particularly golfed)

**Explanation:**

```
,[                                           ,]                               loop until end of input
  +>-->[+]+[->+[--->]<<<]                                                       paren depth calculation: (brute forced black magic)
                                                                                  '(' => 1
                                                                                  ')' => 255
                                                                                  '0123456789+-*/' => 0 
                         <[->>+<<]                                              accumulate paren depth counter
                                  >>>[->>-<<]                                   preserve a data cell uniquely identifying last character
                                               <[,>>]                         if depth counter is nonzero move to cell identifying last character
                                                     ->[+>[>]--<<<++<+]>.     character to final output calculation: (brute forced black magic)
                                                                                '+-*/(' or \0 => 0
                                                                                '0123456789)' => nonzero
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 15 bytes

```javascript
a=>eval(a+')m')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc7BTsMwDIDhe5/C8iU226gAIaFN3Y0nQJwQhyh1u0CXVFk2dZr67CXlgjQESm5WPsv/hz7pgwm2jyvna5naatLVVk66I71QvFc8bYq97qGCSwGgXs4u6uE5BB/W8Opk6MVEqSH6T3HAag2K1PI/aWtx0TZWwow54bFojs5E6x00NPD3oRjOcIE2jRsYwehodiTpC4LEY3CQkt7kHca0XBjvDr6T28631BAiXD9mKEtAwmtKdwvMp3RfPuAvyn9RxnzKqyfMC5jpDWE@pUfMC5hpas6mjD8B0xc)

[tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237465/) claim that "My function return results via throwing an exception"

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 65 bytes

```matlab
@(x)all([sum(x(x<42)*2-81),feval(@(a,b)a(end)~=b,[0,x],'/*-+(')])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcixDoIwGMTx3RfpXWmDVE1IlIT3IAwf2k4IA0o6@epVFxNil8v9f/P1IatPqUWkjCO65XlHRLwcHbWzdUUT/CojWogZKPDTja9mMN3exN6oUtsCij1TaGRazrsApfhdVMXvwJWHTXBbtPUfaGQIpywyrx9Obw)
Anonymous function. Outputs logical 1 for `)` and logical 0 for `(`.
Monstrosity with `eval` is required to handle empty input. Without that case it reduces to:

```matlab
@(x)all([sum(x(x<42)*2-81),x(end)~='/*-+('])
```

which is much easier to comprehend. Ungolfed:

```matlab
@(x)all([                                    % all of the conditions must be met
         sum(x(x<42)*2-81)                   % brackets are unbalanced
                          ,                  % AND
                           x(end)~='/        % last character isn't / AND
                                     *-+('   % isn't * AND ... (so on)
                                          ])
```

Checking of bracket unbalance works by taking only brackets in input: `x(x<42)` and then with multiplication and subtraction transforming `(` into `-1` and `)` into `1`. Then sum of these is converted to logical during execution of `all` - `0` stays logical `0` anything else becomes logical `1`.

Omitted in ungolfed version `eval` additionaly puts `0` before whole input so last character will always exist.

Answer (score 1):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 206 bytes

```
mod B is pr LIST{Int}. ops b p : Nat ~> Nat . var A : Nat . var X Y Z :[Nat]. eq
b(nil)= 0 . eq b(X A)= 0 ^((~ A & 16)*(A xor 41)+ 0 ^ p(X A)). eq p(nil)=
0 . eq p(A X)= 0 ^(A & 22)* -1 ^(A & 1)+ p(X). endm
```

The result is obtained by reducing the `b` function with the input string given as a list of ASCII code points. The output will be `0` for open bracket and `1` for close bracket.

#### Example Session

```
Maude> --- "" -> "("
> red b(nil) .
result Zero: 0
Maude> --- "(1+" -> "("
> red b(40 49 43) .
result Zero: 0
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3" -> ")"
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51) .
result NzNat: 1
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3)" -> ")"
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41) .
result NzNat: 1
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3))-8" -> "("
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41 41 45 56) .
result Zero: 0
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3))-8*(" -> "("
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41 41 45 56 42 40) .
result Zero: 0
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3))-8*((5" -> ")"
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41 41 45 56 42 40 40 53) .
result NzNat: 1
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3))-8*((5)" -> ")"
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41 41 45 56 42 40 40 53 41) .
result NzNat: 1
Maude> --- "(1+(2/3))-8*((5))" -> "("
> red b(40 49 43 40 50 47 51 41 41 45 56 42 40 40 53 41 41) .
result Zero: 0
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod B is
    pr LIST{Int} .

    ops b p : Nat ~> Nat .

    var A : Nat .
    var X Y Z : [Nat] .

    eq b(nil) = 0 .
    eq b(X A) = 0 ^ ((~ A & 16) * (A xor 41) + 0 ^ p(X A)) .

    eq p(nil) = 0 .
    eq p(A X) = 0 ^ (A & 22) * -1 ^ (A & 1) + p(X) .
endm
```

I hope it's not too cheesy to accept input as ASCII code points. Maude *has* a string module, but it's pretty weak and kind of verbose.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 50 bytes

```
is<l>0sp["("=l+f")"=fp-sp]<")"=!f'0Lfp*l!+!!")"f-o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@z2CbHzqC4IFpJQ8k2RztNSVPJNq1At7gg1gbEVExTN/BJK9DKUdRWVAQKpOnm//@vYagNAA)

The algorithm for this one is:

- read in the input, store the last character in a separate stack
- run through all the chars, track `(` vs `)` balance in a saved cell
- test, `last="("` and `last<"0"`
- combine those three tests (paren balance is the 3rd one) to pick output

There's a caveat though.  I don't think `Ly` can handle null character (as opposed to numeric) input.  So it doesn't handle the first test case, which is a null string.

Here's the sausage making...

First part, get input and setup for run

```
i        - read the input onto the stack as codepoints 
 s       - save the last char in the backup cell
  <l>    - switch stacks, load backup cell, switch back to original stack
     0sp - set the backup cell to "0", then delete 0 from stack
```

Count the `(` vs `)` chars, keeping a summary count of the balance

```
[               p] - process one char per iteration, until stack is empty
 "("=              - compare top of stack to "("
     l+            - load balance summary, increments on match
       f           - flip the current character to the top
        ")"=       - compare top of stack to ")"
            fp     - flip current char to the top, delete it
              -    - decrement balance summary if char was ")"
               s   - save balance summary to backup cell
```

Third, test the last character of the input.

```
<            - switch to the stack where we stashed the last char
 ")"=        - compare to ")"
     !       - negate result, we want "not equal"
      f      - pull the character to the top of the stack
       '0L   - test if less than character codepoint for "0"
          fp - pull the char to the top, then delete it
```

Fourth, combine the tests to get an output choice

```
*            - compute "and" of the last two tests
 l!          - load balance summary, negate
   +         - compute "or" of that and the previous test combo
    !!       - convert anything ">0" to "1" via double negate
      ")"f   - add ")" to stack, pull tests results to top
          -  - subtract to change char to "(" if called for
           o - output top of stack as a character
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 69 bytes

```
lambda d:[')','('][len(set(map(d.count,'()')))<2 or d[-1] in '+-*/(']
```

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! This can be golfed by 10 bytes by removing unnecessary whitespace and applying a few of our other [tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY69CsIwFEZ3nyJkufemjaUtghR9ktohNg0G2iTUOIj47FFx8Hf5OOdMXzjHg3d1MttdGtW014rpBgihHQeHFzGpgHrZ@5OLOSABXWlT@ZnpVpaddZBJUSB0ydxbr44Ds45xnnMss@diVdQvojckuf40gd@Oq99CfxLxZsHCbF1Eg48bROkG "Python 3 – Try It Online") Additionally, since this is a [tag:decision-problem], the final step of indexing into `')('` can simply be skipped. Happy golfing!